# Weird access violation at dynamic 2D array even though both indexes are checked for bounds

Tags: c++, arrays, access-violation

I'm having a strange issue. I have a dynamically created 2D array, Content, which has height of _h and width of _w (in my implementation, row is a first parameter and column is second, makes sense in context). Two indexes CAN be out of bounds, that's so by design and if it's so, then the indexes are "wrapped around" the array:

```
Content[v.iget()%_h][u.iget()%_w];
```

v and u are objects of my own class; they have an __int64 value inside and iget() goes like this:

```
return value>>precision;
```

It returns a usual 32-bit int. I "wrap" this int value by height or width with %, and obviously the remainder is always 0 <= r < max. So this % operation also provides a protection against any possible out-of-bounds situations, BUT I sometimes get the access violation exactly on this line. When I look at values of v and u, they're something like -7753978124 - actually, having a negative number in my context isn't supposed to happen (so I have yet to look for what's causing it), but anyway, .iget() should turn it into a normal integer and %_h or %_w should put it into the bounds, but instead I get access violation. How can this be possible?

Comment: Try making your variables unsigned.  The problem most likely occurs when a signed 64-bit int is converted to a signed 32-bit int.

Comment: Unfortunately, they have to be signed by design. I should be able to address, for example, Content[4.59][-23.5] (which is why I have a fixed-point class) - 4.59 is rounded to 4, -23.5 - to -24, and then "wrapped" around the borders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> should turn it into a normal integer

Nope.
`(-1 % 2) == -1`

so expression `x % max` will return values in range of (-max..max).

That's the first problem.

The second problem is this:

```
__int64 a = 0xffffffff00000000;
int b = a >> 32;
printf("%d\n", b);
```

`0xffffffff00000000 >> 32` is `0xffffffff`, which is a negative number `-1` (for signed 32bit int, that is).

You can fix the problem by using expressions like this:

`((x % width) + width)%width`

OR you could fix index with if/else:

```
x %= width;
if (x < 0)
    x += width;
```

Alternatively you could make iget() return `unsigned int`, **but** this will not wrap around negative indexes properly for all widths and heights that are not power of 2.

Comment: Tested it and yes, apparently it was the case - negative numbers give negative results. I somehow thought the remainder works as a usual math remainder. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To be absolutely sure that you aren't running into negative values, you can implement the indexing like the following. It should also be faster than calculating the modulo, which will be an important consideration if you statement occurs inside a tight loop.

```
__int64 v = v.iget();
__int64 u = u.iget();
Content[v < 0 ? 0 : v > _h ? _h : v][u < 0 ? 0 : u > _w ? _w : u];
```